# Swing : BoxLayout fill the entire JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtree, boxlayout

I am adding list of JTree items inside JPanel. I want the parent JPanel to have BoxLayout so that the tree can be added vertically one after another.

The parent JPanel is initialized using :

```
holder.setLayout(new BoxLayout(holder, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        holder.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 24000));
        holder.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 100));
        holder.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 100));
```

The multiple JTree components are added inside :

```
holder.add(tree);
```

So i expect the JTree nodes to be occupying the entire width of my parent JPanel but somehow it is coming like this

[image]

So as you can see it coming in some portion of the parent JPanel. I want it to fill the entire parent Panel(width wise) and be aligned towards left.

**EDIT**

After trying the top-aligned approach mentioned by VGR I got this :

[image]

So the tree are not occupying the entire space still. And when i expand any tree then everything disappears.

I should have also mentioned this earlier  that when the initilization of the parent panel(holder) is done in some other code like this

```
holder.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 24000));
holder.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 100));
holder.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 100));
holder.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
add(holder); // add to the top parent
```

This part is not reachable :( for me. I can only re-change the parent holder as per my requirement.

SSCCE after suggested changes from VGR. This is not compilable but i hope SSC.

```
public BasePanel() extends JPanel{

private javax.swing.JPanel holder;
private GridBagConstraints gbc;
private JPanel treesPanel;

BasePanel(){
  init();
}

public init(){ can't access this method
        holder.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(32767, 25000));
        holder.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 0));
        holder.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 0));
        holder.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(1, 0));
        add(holder);
}

public initTreeComponents(){ // i need to call this for each tree
        this.holder.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        treesPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        this.holder.add(treesPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1;
}

public addTree(JTree tree){// to be called for each tree
  treesPanel.add(tree,gbc);
}
```

Comment: Check the alignment of your JTrees (or whatever other components you're adding to the BoxLayout). More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment).

Comment: Please show an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: An SSCCE is a complete class, with imports and a `main(String[])`, so uncompilable code snippets are certainly not an SSCCE.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think BoxLayout makes child components fill the container.  From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html):

> … for a vertical layout, BoxLayout attempts to make all components in the column as wide as the widest component.

So your JTrees will all be the same width, but that doesn't guarantee they'll be as wide as the container.

Instead, I would use a GridBagLayout:

```
holder.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

// etc.

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 1;
holder.add(tree, gbc);
```

That will result in the JTrees being vertically centered.  If you want them top-aligned, you should put a GridBagLayout panel inside another panel:

```
holder.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel treesPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
holder.add(treesPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

// etc.

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 1;
treesPanel.add(tree, gbc);
```

Comment: I tried the top-aligned approach but still the view is not proper.please look at the edited question once.

Comment: You say that "the tree are not occupying the entire space," but in your picture with the red outline, it looks like they are indeed occupying the entire width of the panel, so I'm not sure what is incorrect about it.  I'm not sure what would cause your other problems;  it works when I try it in a simple test case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding JTrees inside a JScrollPane, ie

```
holder.add(new JScrollPane(tree));
```